# Sorting a nested dictionary in a custom fashion

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a recursively sort a 2 level nested default dict. I have not been able to figure out how to do this properly. My problem statement is given below:

1. First level key must be a natural sort.
2. Second level key must be sorted in a specific order. I have tried to create a list whose indices represent the order of the elements. My code snippet is given below:

   ```
   import operator
   import collections
   trade_group_totals = collections.defaultdict(lambda:collections.defaultdict(float))    
   trade_group_totals['foo']['ABC'] = 100
   trade_group_totals['foo']['XYZ'] = 50
   trade_group_totals['bar']['ABC'] = 150
   trade_group_totals['bar']['XYZ'] = 250
   ```

My sorting index comparison:

```
trade_groups = ['XYZ', 'ABC']

def TradeGroupSort(trade_group):
   return trade_groups.index(trade_group)   

def SortTotals(totals, sort_function_one, sort_function_two):
  return [
      (k1, v1) for k1, v1 in [(k, sorted(v.iteritems(), key=sort_function_two))
           for k, v in sorted(totals.iteritems(), key=sort_function_one)]]
```

I am invoking the function as follows:

```
SortTotals(
    trade_group_totals, operator.itemgetter(0),
    sort_function_two=lambda x: operator.methodcaller('TradeGroupSort', x))
```

My expected output should be:

```
[('bar', [('XYZ', 50), ('ABC', 100)]), ('foo', [('XYZ', 250), ('ABC', 150)])]
```

But the generated output is

```
[('bar', [('XYZ', 50), ('ABC', 150)]), ('foo', [('ABC', 150), ('XYZ', 250)])]
```

Comment: How do you get an output of `foo` having `XYZ==250` and `ABC==150`, when `50` and `100` were the input?

Comment: It was a typo. That has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked for me. This is the UGLY sorting that I came up with.

```
def TradeGroupSort(trade_group):
  """Sorting the trade group."""
  group, _ = trade_group  # The value is a tuple ('XYZ', 50) for e.g.
  return trade_groups.index(group)
```

I could not think of a better solution than that. I invoked this function as follows:

```
SortTotals(trade_group_totals, operator.itemgetter(0), TradeGroupSort)
```

This returns the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It may look a little criptic, but it is actually very simple. First you create the list of the primary key and value (the secondary dictionary) from the items method. You have an explicit ordering, so instead of try to order by that, you can simply take the element from the internal dictionary with that order, sorting it by definition as you wish.

Then you can just sort the principal key the way you prefere (in this case just by simple ordering).

```
items = [ (k,sorted(v.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)) 
                              for k,v in trade_group_totals.items()]
items_sortes = sorted(items,reverse=True)
```

Depending on what you mean for natural ordering in you specific problem you can change the secondary sort without worry about the first one

Comment: Hi Enrico, I am afraid that you suggestion did not work. Your suggested solution returns the following:
[('foo', [('XYZ', 250), ('ABC', 150)]), ('bar', [('XYZ', 50), ('ABC', 100)])]

I am afraid that is not what I want.

Comment: just put both the reverse parameter to False instead of True